# Counting messages through sendmail

Tags: log-files, sendmail, logparser

The back story here is that I would like to start using an SMTP service to start sending my email (currently sent though sendmail running locally on the server), but in order to get a good idea of what this will cost I need to understand how many messages I am sending.

The best way I can think of to get a round figure is the sendmail logs- but I'm not sure exactly how to do this.

I do know that a single message usually (if not always) has multiple lines- if I knew how they were associated together I could write something to parse the log and count uniques (????).

Since I don't know what that is I am trying to figure out how to identify 1 record for each actual request and count those...

```
sudo cat maillog.* | grep 'mailer=relay' | grep '@' | wc
```

This amounts to about about 1/7th of the total lines in the logs, which conversely suggests that a message has an average of 7 records.

Is this a reasonable way to do this? Is there a better way?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `mailstats` program, typically part of the Sendmail distribution.